# SSH Tunnel very slow

Tags: networking, ssh, performance, tunnel

I just setup an SSH Tunnel and it is very slow. On the network the ssh server is connected to has a download speed of 25 mbps and an upload speed of 4 mbps. I tested my internet speed and I'm actually getting a little faster than that. The network the computer that I'm using to connect to the ssh server is way faster so speed isn't a problem. When I try to load the site retro.hackaday.com on the network my ssh server is on loads almost instantly but when I connect to the ssh server (even on the same network) it takes several minutes to load. Why is it so slow? I'm using FireFox and the command `sudo ssh -D xxx -C -N -P xxx anonymous@xxx.xxx.xxx`

Edit:

Ok. So I pinged the ssh server from the local network and I got this.

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.xxx: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=73.488 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.xxx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.696 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.xxx: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=135.368 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.xxx: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.374 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.xxx: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=48.818 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.xxx: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=3.706 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.xxx: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=4.597 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.xxx: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=3.646 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.xxx: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=26.103 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.xxx ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 9 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 3.374/33.644/135.368/43.045 ms
```

Comment: So what is the ping time?

Comment: I'm using firefox with the command sudo ssh -D xxx -C -N -P xxx anonymous@xxx.xxx.xxx so how do I get ping time?

Comment: just, open a command prompt or terminal window, and ping the ssh server

Comment: Ok here's what I got.                                                                                      64 bytes from 192.168.x.xxx: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=29.259 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.x.xxx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.220 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.x.xxx: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=64.016 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.x.xxx: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.934 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.x.xxx: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=106.849 ms

Comment: Can you also provide a trace?
And a ping the opposite way?

Comment: So those ping times are not consistent which indicates a problem.  Why did you feel the need to mask a intranet ip address?

Comment: I have the same issue. My connections over dynamic SSH SOCKS5 proxy is always slow!! I dont undertand the reasons.